# repeat string in a line using sed

Tags: sed

I would like to repeat each line's content of a file, any quick solution using sed.

supposed the input file is

> abc
>  def
>  123

The expected ouput is:

> abcabc
>  defdef
>  123123

Answer (score 8):

```
sed 's \(.*\) \1\1 ' infile
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
echo -e 'aaA\nbbB\nccC' | sed 's/.*/&&/'
aaAaaA
bbBbbB
ccCccC
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 'h;G;s/\n//' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

It's even simpler if you take advantage of the variable `\0`, which holds the string that was matched:

`sed 's/.*/\0\0/'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`awk '{print $0$0}' temp.txt`